# I need some help understanding some code involving Linked Lists in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

This might be a very dumb question. I have an assignment to create a new node and add a value to it. I've been looking for help online and I came across this code:

```
head = new(struct node);
```

I assume it is a way of creating a new node and assigning it to head, right? Is it just a simpler way of writing this?

```
node *new_node = new node;
head = new_node;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That is correct. `head = new(struct node);` is using the assingment operator and safes you one line compared to

`node *new_node = new node;
head = new_node;` .

I am not sure but I think modern compilers even optimize both inputs to the same assembly code, but you acutually should use `head = new(struct node);` because it is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

The `struct` is unnecessary:

```
head = new node;
```

is all you need to write. Conventionally you'd add brackets to be more consistent with classes with parameters in their constructors:

```
head = new node();
```

This is identical to your second example of creating in a temporary value then copying into `head`. Most compilers will optimise away the temporary value.